# how to write more concise lambda function of sortBy, unionBy, etc

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, lambda

Functions like `sortBy` and `unionBy` take a lambda function as argument. The lambda function often does `compare` or `eq` after taking some part from the element of the list. For example,

```
f v1 v2 = sortBy (\x y -> compare (fst x) (fst y)) $ 
            unionBy (\x y -> (fst x) == (fst y)) (zip v1 [0..]) (zip v2 [0..])
```

Just wondering if the lambda function `\x y -> compare (fst x) (fst y)` can be written more concisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find that

```
compare `on` fst
```

is what I write when I have to write `\x y -> compare (fst x) (fst y)`.

You can find `on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c` in `Data.Function`. So your code will be

```
f v1 v2 = sortBy (compare `on` fst) $ 
            unionBy ((==) `on` fst) (zip v1 [0..]) (zip v2 [0..])
```

Comment: `compare 'on' fst` yields "Syntax error on 'on', Perhaps you intended to use -XTemplateHaskell". I ended up using `on compare fst` instead.

Comment: It uses backquotes (the key above the tab), not simple quotes. ```, not `'`. The standard trick to convert a function to inline form.

Answer (score 7):

Besides the already mentioned `on`, the [`comparing`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/libraries/base/Data-Ord.html) function from `Data.Ord` is directly applicable here.

```
\x y -> compare (f x) (f y) === comparing f
```

Comment: Specifically, ``comparing ≡ (compare `on`)``.

Answer (score 3):

I like the `on` function from Data.Function for this.

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List

f v1 v2 = sortBy (compare `on` fst) $ 
        unionBy ((==) `on` fst) (zip v1 [0..]) (zip v2 [0..])
```